# Display the count down in middle of the progress bar

Tags: android, xml

I am having the progress bar with count down in an decreasing order.I wanna show the textview in the middle of the progressbar.

Inside Relative layout, I used `progressbar` and `text view` as-

```
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBarToday" 
style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
android:indeterminate="false" 
android:max="60" 
android:progress="45" 
android:progressDrawable= "@drawable/circular_progress_bar" /> 

<TextView android:id="@+id/textView1" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
```

Comment: https://github.com/Todd-Davies/ProgressWheel. looking for a circular progress wheel?

Comment: no.... i need to align the text view inside the progressbar

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: inside Relative layout, i used progressbar and text view ..

Comment: <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarToday"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="60"
        android:progress="45"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/circular_progress_bar" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />